# How to return exception message with success value in C# windows application?

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to return a success or failure value from one class to another. In case of failure, I also need to return the error message to the other class. How can this be achieved with a function returning integer?

**clsDAL.cs**

```
    public int Insert(string name, string address)
            {               
                try
                {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.CommandText = "sp_demo";
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id",1);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name",name);
                int i = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      

                return i;
                }//try

                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    return -1;     // Incase of failure need to return Exception error
                }

            }
```

**clsBLL.cs**

```
       public int InsertData(string name, string address)
            {
               int i = dobj.InsertTable(name, address);

               if (i == 1)
              {
               MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted successfully");
              }
              else
              {
               MessageBox.Show("Insertion failed");   // Show the exception message here
              }
           }
```

Comment: Why don't you just let the exception bubble up to the place where you can actually do something about it? Why bother returning an integer?

Comment: As you've discovered, you can't store a string in an `int`.  Your method could return a `string`, or a custom object.  Or probably better, just let the exception escape the method.  If you want to add custom information to the exception you can catch it and wrap it in a custom exception and throw that.  But returning `-1` and ignoring the rest of the exception tells the calling code, and you, exactly nothing about what went wrong.  What specifically is the purpose of catching the exception where you're currently catching it?  How are you planning to handle the exception there?

Comment: A more useful pattern is to `throw` a new, meaningful exception from `Insert` that indicates that the call to `sp_demo` failed and including the reported exception as the _inner exception_ for your custom exception. What you really want is something like "Failed to insert name 'Foo'." with "Duplicate values not allowed for Name." as the inner exception, i.e. what happened and why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the try-catch blocks to the parent method so that you have the actual error message ready to be used.

Couple things to take care of, looking at your code...

1. Suggest to catch a more specific exception like SqlException type in addition to the generic exception. Specific exception types always give you more granular information on the error.
2. Ensure to close connection and dispose off relevant objects in a finally block as catch blocks shortcut your regular flow when exception occurs. using-statements would be much better as it is taken care implicitly.

Here is a sample edit for your code...

```
public int InsertData(string name, string address)
{           
    try
    {
        dobj.InsertTable(name, address);
        MessageBox.Show("Record Inserted successfully");
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlException)
    {
        var messageBuilder= new StringBuilder();
        messageBuilder.AppendLine(sqlException.Message);
        foreach(SqlError sqlError in sqlException.Errors)
        {
            messageBuilder.AppendLine(sqlError.Message);
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Insertion failed with errors - " + messageBuilder.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Insertion failed with errors - " + exception.Message);
    }
}
```